# Парсинг погоды с помощью GSON

Tags: java, android, json

Подскажите, как правильно пользоваться GSON, или где можно найти информацию о его применении?

Хочу взять данные `WeatherOpenApi` и создать новый объект `Weather`, заполнив его переменные `name`, `main`, `maxtemp`  полученными данными.

За счёт каких действий данные, которые я получаю в виде json должны распределиться по переменным класса? Как пример смотрел [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/gson.php), но там количество переменных объекта равно количеству аргументов в json - а в моем случае получается много лишней информации - как отсеять лишнюю?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class Weather {
    String main;
    String name;
    double maxtemp;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String jsonlink = "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-0.13,\"lat\":51.51},\"weather\":[{\"id\":310,\"main\":\"Drizzle\",\"description\":\"light intensity drizzle rain\",\"icon\":\"09d\"},{\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10d\"}],\"base\":\"cmc stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":280.87,\"pressure\":1007,\"humidity\":87,\"temp_min\":280.15,\"temp_max\":281.75},\"wind\":{\"speed\":4.6,\"deg\":230},\"clouds\":{\"all\":90},\"dt\":1459925764,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":5168,\"message\":0.0045,\"country\":\"GB\",\"sunrise\":1459920191,\"sunset\":1459968198},\"id\":2643743,\"name\":\"London\",\"cod\":200}";

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    Weather weather = gson.fromJson(jsonlink, Weather.class);

    Log.i("Name", weather.name);
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто не объявляйте поля в классе, данные которых вам не нужны.

Например если приходит такой ответ

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 139,
    "lat": 35
  },
  "main": {
    "temp": 289.5,
    "humidity": 89,
    "pressure": 1013,
    "temp_min": 287.04,
    "temp_max": 292.04
  },
  "dt": 1369824698,
  "id": 1851632,
  "name": "Shuzenji",
  "cod": 200
}
```

А из него нужны только объект main, id, name, code, то достаточно будет объявить классы с такими полями:

```
public class Weather {

    public Main main;
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public int code;
}

public class Main {
    public float temp;
    public int humidity;
    public int pressure;
    @SerializedName("temp_min")
    public float tempMax;
    @SerializedName("temp_max")
    public float tempMin;
}
```

И тогда GSON автоматически заполнит их используя полученный JSON ответ.

При создании классов-моделей необходимо учитывать структуру JSON, т.е. если попытаться преобразовать приведенный выше JSON в класс `Main` таким образом:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Main main = gson.fromJson(json, Main.class);
```

то в этом случае будет выброшено исключение, либо не правильно заполненный объект, если поля их будут частично совпадать, т.к. корневым элементом в структуре ответа является объект `Weather`, и `Gson` будет пытаться заполнить его поля.

Comment: @Denis, спасибо!